# Как правильно заносить строковые значения содержащие апостроф?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте.
Когда я выполняю SQL-запрос в своем коде на java, через driverManager, то получаю в базе вместо апострофа - \u0027.

[image: Workbench]

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/films?", connInfo);
         PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO films(name_film, rating, description, poster, path, year_of_release) VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

        for (File film:films) {

            String actors = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(film.getPath() + "/actors.txt")));
            String description = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(film.getPath() + "/description.txt")));
            String genres = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(film.getPath() + "/genres.txt")));
            String names = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(film.getPath() + "/names.txt")));
            String Producer = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(film.getPath() + "/Producer.txt")));
            String year = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(film.getPath() + "/year.txt")));

            String[] namesArray = names.split(" / ");
            for (int i = 0; i<namesArray.length; i++) {
                namesArray[i] = namesArray[i].trim();
            }



            statement.setString(1, new Gson().toJson(namesArray));
            statement.setInt(2,5);
            statement.setString(3, description);
            statement.setString(4,film.getPath() + "/poster.jpg");
            statement.setString(5, film.getPath() + "filmName");
            statement.setInt(6,Integer.parseInt(year.trim()));
            statement.executeUpdate();


        }//for
    }
```

Когда я выполняю похожей запрос через Workbench, то все в порядке:

```
INSERT INTO films(name_film, rating, description, poster, path, year_of_release) VALUE ("world's dog", 5, "Привет мир", "Пока мир", "world's dog", 2017);
```

[image: Workbench 2]

Comment: Возможно кодировка отличается при работе через рабочий код и с IDE.

Comment: В idea intellij и текстовых файлах стоит UTF-8: [скрин-1](http://vfl.ru/fotos/8b05fb7620922073.html) [скрин-2](http://vfl.ru/fotos/b118b7c420922074.html). Как в Workbench посмотреть не знаю, но если сохранить скрипт и открыть Notepad++ будет стоять UTF-8

Comment: [скрин-3](http://vfl.ru/fotos/53e31d1420922155.html)

Comment: У вас не задана кодировка подключения в коде. Вот я и предположил вышеописанное. Попробуйте явно прописать в драйвер кодировку так: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/films?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8`.

Comment: Извините, не показал весь код. Это я делал.

Comment: Properties connInfo = new Properties();
        connInfo.put("user", "root");
        connInfo.put("password", "angel");
        connInfo.put("useUnicode","true"); // (1)
        connInfo.put("charSet", "UTF8"); // (2)